# How to uninstall Vivaldi browser?

Tags: 20.04, vivaldi

How to uninstall Vivaldi browser?

I've used the command "$ sudo apt-get --purge remove vivaldi"

But it simply doesn't work, and issues a notification like this

"$ Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done

E: Unable to locate package vivaldi "

But the browser still remains on my device

Comment: This is why I like `gdebi`. Find the original .deb (or a newer one if you deleted it) and open it with gdebi. If it's already installed, it will offer you the chance to uninstall it from the GUI.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you used the repository to install. The package name is vivaldi-stable
Hence,

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove vivaldi-stable
```

If you installed the deb package directly, follow the instructions on their [site](https://help.vivaldi.com/desktop/install-update/how-to-uninstall-vivaldi/):

1. While using Vivaldi, open Vivaldi menu button Vivaldi menu > Help > About. Or type vivaldi://about to the address field.
2. Make a note of the Profile Path, minus Default.
3. Open Files and search for the Vivaldi folder following the path you noted above.
4. Quit Vivaldi.
5. Delete the entire Vivaldi folder.

Comment: Thanks mate, sorry I am really a noob in the Ubuntu Linux operating system.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to removing the package in other answers...

If you want to clear all Vivaldi state this is the best I have found:

```sh
rm -i -rv ~/.cache/vivaldi ~/.local/lib/vivaldi ~/.config/vivaldi
```

Shown command prompts for every file, remove the `-i` to delete everything with prompts.